# Wordpress table on a page from Mysql source

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress for my site and on a page I want to show a table that containing various informations.

I've tried several plugins but all of these allow me to create this table manually, importing a csv or xml.

I would like that this table on a page take data from MySql (a table in the database) so it is not static and when I update the table in the database I wish that I update the table in the site also, so adding or removing rows depending on whether the data is increased or decreased.

Do you know plugins that allow to create tables that take data from a table in the database?

The only one I've found is WpDataTables but it's not free.
I'm looking for something open source so you can modify it if necessary.

Thanks to all

Comment: create this yourself. Google "wp_query" if you want to pull posts and "$wpdb" for custom tables.